# Arreglo de cadenas e indicador

Tags: java, array

necsito que me ayuden con lo siguiente, el usuario ingresa el numero de una tarjeta credito ej: 4892 6913 2652 9108, y el primer digito corresponde al sector(Visa,MasterCard,AmericanExpress), los siguientes dos digitos(89), corresponde al banco. entonces debo convertir ese String en un arreglo para poder navegar. yo hice lo siguiente:

metodo:

```
public String metodoTarjetaCredito(String info) {
    String res = null;
    String sector = null;
    String banco= null;

        String[] parts = info.split(" ");
          for (int i = 0; i < info.length(); i++){           
         String part1 = parts[0];
         String part2 = parts[1];
         String part3 = parts[2];
         String part4 = parts[3];               

         if(part1.indexOf(0)==5){
              sector="MasterCard";
         }else if(part1.indexOf(0)==4){
              sector="Visa";
         }else if(part1.indexOf(0)==3){
              sector="American Express";
         }else{
             System.out.println("Sector no existe");
         }

         if(part1.indexOf(1, 2)==89){
             banco="Colpatria";
         }          


          }
          res="Sector:"+sector+"\n Banco:"+banco;





    return res;
}
```

y el Main esta asi:

```
  @EJB
private static MySessionRemote mySession;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese numero tarjeta");
    String tarjeta = scn.next();
    System.out.println(mySession.metodoTarjetaCredito(tarjeta));




}
```

al ejecutar me salta error.

Answer (score 0):

viendo tu codigo he observado dos cosas:

si le vas a pasar el numero de la tarjeta entero , en lugar de usar

```
String tarjeta = scn.next();
```

deberias usar:

```
String tarjeta = scn.nextLine();
```

Y para coger el primer dígito de la tarjeta deberás usar:

```
part1.charAt(0)
```

en lugar de:

```
part1.indexOf(0)
```

como lo que te devuelve este método es un objeto de tipo Character , lo puedes comparar de la siguiente forma:

```
if (Character.toString(part1.charAt(0)).equals("4")) {}
```